# Is there an error in the CoreDataBooks sample regarding dates?

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

I notice the following apparent error, and I am curious as to its significance:

Open the CoreDataBooks sample. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html

Choose any book - let's say Bill Bryson, Down Under.

Select Edit.

Click Copyright.

Select January 1, 2010 and click Save.

The date saved is January 1, 2009.  This occurs for many other dates as well, always one year off.

Now curiously, if you change the date to January 14, 2010, all is well and stays ok from that point on.

I have done this now about 100 times, and cannot detect a pattern that allows me to see what is causing it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

What if you change it to January 2, 2010? I'll bet it's a time zone / 00:00:00.00 o'clock thing.